# Can we remove the google index for the Comms Room?

Tags: discussion, chat

Is there any way to make it so that Google wouldn't index the chats from the Comms Room? Why is it currently set up the way it is?

Comment: Are you talking about existing stuff going back ~4 years (that I assume is already indexed)?  Or the few residual posts that are showing up now?

Comment: I could be ok with either situation. The goal would be making chat a place that people are more comfortable to use, without feeling like it could be a resource for people to dig up embarrassing out-of-context quotes. That said, we could get that without going back and removing all the old history.

Comment: Why? If you're making a request, you should give *reasons*.

Comment: I tagged it as "discussion", not "feature request"

Answer (score 12):

Eh, sorta... You can set robots.txt to not index the transcripts of particular rooms or the whole site. But:

1. That doesn't stop anyone from copying the content, and allowing it to be indexed from their site.
2. Google's a bit slow at updating the "rules" from robots.txt if it's already indexed a site.
3. Rule #5 - The Internet Never Forgives or Forgets

Comment: Not worried about the internet forgetting, but if we made the Comms room resistant to casual browsing looking for out-of-context quotes that would make someone look foolish or something, it would be better than it is now.